# Can a journal be freely indexed?

Tags: publications

Am I allowed to compile the index to a journal and publish it, or should I ask permission to the journal first?

(By index I mean a list of all articles in all issues of the journal)

Comment: What do you mean by "indexed"? Are you thinking of the kind of index which says "if you're interested in ____ topic, look on this page"?

Comment: @Allure Or does he mean “indexed” as in “have a computer program automatically add every word in the journal (aside maybe some extremely common words like ‘the’) into a structured field that then records their position in the journal to allow for computer searching”?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's allowed since (1) Google Scholar and many other databases do it and (2) it's in the interest of a journal that its content is as referenced as possible... but IANAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to ask, because it is not obvious whether you can use their materials or not. As you can see from the [link](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/cc-licenses/) there are different types of cc licenses.